# AppSync + DynamoDB: Query with filter doesn't return all valid items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I have Appsync API connecting to a Dynamo table.

Dynamo table has data : ("id" is key and "year" is sort key)

```
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------| 
|      id      |     year    |     name    |    class    |   subject   |    
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|   001        |    2017     |     Tom     |     E1      |     Math    |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|   002        |    2017     |     Mary    |     E1      |     Math    |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|   003        |    2017     |     Peter   |     E1      |     Math    |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
```

the schema

```
type Query {
    listStudents(filter: TableStudentFilterInput, limit: Int, nextToken: String): StudentConnection
}

type StudentConnection {
    items: [Student]
    nextToken: String
}

input TableStudentFilterInput {
    id: TableStringFilterInput
    year: TableStringFilterInput
    name: TableStringFilterInput
    class: TableStringFilterInput
    subject: TableStringFilterInput
}

type Student {
    id: String!
    year: String!
    name: String
    class: String
    subject: String
}
```

Query:

```
query listStudentByYear {
  listStudents (filter:{year:{eq:"2017"}}) {
    items {
      id
      year
      name
      class
      subject
    }
  }
}
```

The issue: The query return 001 and 002, but not 003.

When I tried to update "id" from 003 to 004, then the query returns correctly 001, 002, 004.

This weird issue happens quite frequently, after some times, the AppSync query returns an incomplete result (missing some).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen to return a next token with it? Dynamo sometimes won't paginate fully, if that's the case it will return a token with the response.

Comment: @Jeff Bailey: yes, I didn't notice the nextToken. The weird thing, even it returns full items, it also returns a token where nothing left.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2233) thread from `amplify-js` issues.

Essentially what is happening is a limit is applied **before** the filter. So if you have a limit of 20 and `003` is entry number 21 it will not be included in the filter operation.

A workaround here is to remove the limit from you resolver in the `AWS AppSync Console`

So change this:

```
#set( $ListRequest = {
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "limit": $limit
})
```

to this:

```
#set( $ListRequest = {
  "version": "2017-02-28",
} )
```

Now this isn't a graceful workaround as the DynamoDB [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Limit) will only return 1MB of data meaning this solution will not work for large (practical) implementations.